# How to make this HTML object in a middle and one line?

Tags: html, css

Here you can see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kAQrX/1/

I want the magnifier, search text and search box (input) to display in one line, and in a middle of the `#search` div.

I'm out of ideas now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This** :

```
.magnifier {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 3px;
    float:left; //<----
}
```

See Feedle [**http://jsfiddle.net/kAQrX/2/**](http://jsfiddle.net/kAQrX/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the css background-image property and a left padding, instead of an image tag! :)

E.g.

```
.search_content {
  background: url('http://www.iconeasy.com/icon/thumbnails/System/WebGloss%203D/Magnifier%20Icon.jpg') no-repeat;
  padding-left: 55px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAQrX/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can display it `inline`, or as `inline-block`. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kAQrX/3/)

Answer (score 1):

there you go:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="search">

        <div class="search_content">
            <span class="search_text">SEARCH:</span>
            <input type="text" name="query" class="search_box">
            <img src="http://www.iconeasy.com/icon/thumbnails/System/WebGloss%203D/Magnifier%20Icon.jpg" class="magnifier">
        </div>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#search {
    background: url("images/search.png") no-repeat;
    width: 382px;
    height: 41px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.magnifier {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    margin: 3px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.search_text {
    margin-left: 3px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 1px black;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.search_box {
    width: 162px;
    height: 33px;
    padding: 0px 12px 2px 10px;
}

.searchbox_content {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following:

```
.searchbox_content {
  display: inline;
}
```

to get the 3 elements in one line.

To get them into the center of `#search` you can add the `text-align`-Attribute:

```
#search {
  text-align:center;
}
```